# Do I need a Thailand Transit Visa if going from India to Vietnam via BKK where the layover is 9 hours approx ? I am travelling by Thai Airways

Tags: visas, transit

I am an Indian National holding Indian Passport.  Do I need a Thailand Transit Visa if going from India to Vietnam via BKK where the layover is 9 hours approx ? I am travelling by Thai Airways.

Comment: (That question was asked by an Indian but the answer gives full details for any nationality; I've now edited it to remove "for Indian Citizen" from the title.)

Answer (score 0):

You **do not require** any transit visa if the **connection time is less than 12 hours**. Although it applies for Thai Airways (your case), some airlines do not have the 12 hour exception. You can see the details below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Thailand#Transit